# Out of Range Check for WLAN Network

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

Does anyone know of a universal mechanism to check on a client device if it is still within range of a wireless network and can communicate on it? One idea is to ping the gateway, but some networks disable pinging.

Comment: Did you need to cope with "hidden" networks that don't broadcast their SSID?

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is an interface on each network that will accept some kind of connection and provide a response, or unless each network has a uniquely different IP address range, then no.